Convert pandas series of strings into PeriodIndex, quarterly
I have a column of strings which represent quarters (format '%Y%q') which I want to convert to PeriodIndex. How to do this? Nothing is working, can't find a strptime function that takes a format string and deals with Quarterly.
out[0]
 
0     200001
1     200002
2     200003
3     200004
4     200101
       ...  
94    202303
95    202304
96    202401
97    202402
98    202403
Name: 0, Length: 99, dtype: int64

Want:
PeriodIndex(['2000Q1',... '2024Q3'], dtype='period[Q-DEC]')


Regex replace
Firstly, what you're showing isn't string data, it's dtype: int64. I'm going to assume you're reading from a CSV or something and you can go back and fix that.
You can simply use regex to convert to the right format. Note that %q doesn't have a leading zero (per docs for pandas.Period.strftime).
# Example setup
s = pd.Series(['202304', '202401', '202402', '202403'])

pd.PeriodIndex(
    s.str.replace(r'(\d{4})0(\d)', r'\1Q\2', regex=True),
    freq='Q')

PeriodIndex(['2023Q4', '2024Q1', '2024Q2', '2024Q3'], dtype='period[Q-DEC]')

Regex breakdown:

\d A digit
{4} Repeated four times
(...) A group
\1 Reference back to group 1


You can use pd.PeriodIndex.from_fields.
With integers (you say you have strings, but your sample has dtype: int64), use floor division for the year (//), and modulo for the quarter (%):
import pandas as pd

data = [202401, 202402, 202403, 202404]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': data})

df['Quarters'] = pd.PeriodIndex.from_fields(year=df['Dates'] // 100, 
                                            quarter=df['Dates'] % 10, 
                                            freq='Q')

Output:
df['Quarters']

0    2024Q1
1    2024Q2
2    2024Q3
3    2024Q4
Name: Quarters, dtype: period[Q-DEC]

With strings, you can use Series.astype to convert to integers and do the same as above, or slice via Series.str and convert afterwards:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': data}, dtype=str)

df['Quarters'] = pd.PeriodIndex.from_fields(year=df['Dates'].str[:4].astype(int), 
                                            quarter=df['Dates'].str[5:].astype(int), 
                                            freq='Q')

Note that the use of pd.PeriodIndex in this way is deprecated since version 2.2.0 (e.g. pd.PeriodIndex(year=[2024], quarter=[1])).

Performance comparison
Adding the pd.PeriodIndex method used in the answer by @wjandrea:
s = pd.Series(['202401', '202402', '202403', '202404'])
s = pd.concat([s]*250)

%timeit pd.PeriodIndex.from_fields(year=s.str[:4].astype(int), quarter=s.str[5:].astype(int), freq='Q')

1.65 ms ± 273 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit pd.PeriodIndex(s.str.replace(r'(\d{4})0(\d)', r'\1Q\2', regex=True), freq='Q')

21.9 ms ± 833 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# alternative for replace with regex
%timeit pd.PeriodIndex(s.str[:4] + 'Q' + s.str[5:], freq='Q')

21.3 ms ± 651 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Using pd.PeriodIndex.from_fields will be much faster. Used directly on integers it will be faster still:
s = pd.Series([202401, 202402, 202403, 202404])
s = pd.concat([s]*250)

%timeit pd.PeriodIndex.from_fields(year=s // 100, quarter=s % 10, freq='Q')

1.05 ms ± 142 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

